# Can the message "Don't forget you can mark this answer as the accepted answer" only come up when the waiting period is over?

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, accepting

I upvoted an answer, and a popup appeared with something along the lines of "Don't forget you can mark this answer as the accepted answer". I tried to accept the answer, and then another popup mentioned "You can accept this answer in 3 minutes".

Can the "Don't forget..." message be displayed only when the accept-an-answer waiting time is up?

Comment: Once again Werner, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This change will go out with the next deploy.